# Errors when using rocketter to deploy to recently upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 box

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, phpseclib, rocketeer

I've recently updated my Ubuntu server from 14.04 to 16.04, but now I'm getting the error show below when I try & deploy using rocketeer, however it seems that the deployment continues and completed successfully despite these errors.

```
PHP Warning:  unpack(): Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 1 in phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 2826
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar:0
PHP   2. require() /Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar:16
PHP   3. Rocketeer\Facades\Console::run() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/bin/rocketeer:26
PHP   4. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic($method = *uninitialized*, $args = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/bin/rocketeer:26
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run($input = *uninitialized*, $output = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/illuminate/support/Illum
inate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:205
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun($input = *uninitialized*, $output = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfon
y/Component/Console/Application.php:124
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand($command = *uninitialized*, $input = *uninitialized*, $output = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer
.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
PHP   8. Illuminate\Console\Command->run($input = *uninitialized*, $output = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/C
onsole/Application.php:889
PHP   9. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run($input = *uninitialized*, $output = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/illuminate/console/I
lluminate/Console/Command.php:100
PHP  10. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute($input = *uninitialized*, $output = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Compone
nt/Console/Command/Command.php:253
PHP  11. Rocketeer\Console\Commands\DeployCommand->fire() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/illuminate/console/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:112
PHP  12. Rocketeer\Abstracts\AbstractCommand->fireTasksQueue($tasks = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Console/Commands/DeployCommand.php:
39
PHP  13. Rocketeer\Abstracts\AbstractCommand->time($callback = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Abstracts/AbstractCommand.php:176
PHP  14. Rocketeer\Abstracts\AbstractCommand->Rocketeer\Abstracts\{closure}() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Abstracts/AbstractCommand.php:270
PHP  15. Rocketeer\Services\Tasks\TasksQueue->run($tasks = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Abstracts/AbstractCommand.php:173
PHP  16. Rocketeer\Services\Tasks\TasksQueue->runSynchronously($pipeline = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Tasks/TasksQueue.php:
130
PHP  17. Rocketeer\Services\Tasks\TasksQueue->Rocketeer\Services\Tasks\{closure}() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Tasks/TasksQueue.php:222
PHP  18. Rocketeer\Services\Tasks\TasksQueue->executeJob($job = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Tasks/TasksQueue.php:122
PHP  19. Rocketeer\Abstracts\AbstractTask->fire() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Tasks/TasksQueue.php:190
PHP  20. Rocketeer\Services\Display\QueueTimer->time($task = *uninitialized*, $callback = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Abstracts/Abstr
actTask.php:144
PHP  21. Rocketeer\Abstracts\AbstractTask->Rocketeer\Abstracts\{closure}() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Display/QueueTimer.php:39
PHP  22. Rocketeer\Tasks\Deploy->execute() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Abstracts/AbstractTask.php:143
PHP  23. Rocketeer\Bash->isSetup() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Tasks/Deploy.php:37
PHP  24. Rocketeer\Bash->fileExists($file = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Traits/BashModules/Flow.php:34
PHP  25. Rocketeer\Bash->checkStatement($condition = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Traits/BashModules/Filesystem.php:148
PHP  26. Rocketeer\Bash->runRaw($commands = *uninitialized*, $array = *uninitialized*, $trim = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Traits/Bas
hModules/Filesystem.php:270
PHP  27. Rocketeer\Services\Connections\RemoteHandler->run(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Traits/BashModules/Core.php:1
56
PHP  28. Rocketeer\Services\Connections\RemoteHandler->__call($method = *uninitialized*, $parameters = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Tr
aits/BashModules/Core.php:156
PHP  29. call_user_func_array:{phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Connections/RemoteHandler.php:149}(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) phar:///Users
/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Connections/RemoteHandler.php:149
PHP  30. Illuminate\Remote\Connection->run($commands = *uninitialized*, $callback = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/src/Rocketeer/Services/Connections/
RemoteHandler.php:149
PHP  31. Illuminate\Remote\Connection->getGateway() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/illuminate/remote/Illuminate/Remote/Connection.php:109
PHP  32. Illuminate\Remote\SecLibGateway->connect($username = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/illuminate/remote/Illuminate/Remote/Connection.php
:231
PHP  33. Net_SFTP->login($username = *uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/illuminate/remote/Illuminate/Remote/SecLibGateway.php:86
PHP  34. Net_SSH2->_get_channel_packet($client_channel = *uninitialized*, $skip_extended = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/p
hpseclib/Net/SFTP.php:441
PHP  35. Net_SSH2->_get_binary_packet() phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:2974
PHP  36. Net_SSH2->_filter($payload = *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:2771
PHP  37. unpack(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) phar:///Users/toby/src/bitbucket.org/limtool/limtool/rocketeer.phar/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:2826
```

I've tried debugging, but it looks like the phpseclib packages does a load of binary string extraction form the SSH2 connections, and I have no idea where to start with debugging this.

Could it be to do with an updated version of openssl?

Here's the list of packages & versions it's using…

```
anahkiasen/rocketeer      2.2.3   Rocketeer is a fast and simple deployer for the PHP world
d11wtq/boris              v1.0.10 A tiny, but robust REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop) for PHP.
illuminate/config         v4.2.17
illuminate/console        v4.2.17
illuminate/container      v4.2.17
illuminate/events         v4.2.17
illuminate/filesystem     v4.2.17
illuminate/log            v4.2.17
illuminate/remote         v4.2.16
illuminate/support        v4.2.17
kzykhys/parallel          v0.1.0  Simple multitasking library
monolog/monolog           1.20.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and vario...
nesbot/carbon             1.21.0  A simple API extension for DateTime.
patchwork/utf8            v1.3.1  Portable and performant UTF-8, Unicode and Grapheme Clusters fo...
phpseclib/phpseclib       0.3.10  PHP Secure Communications Library - Pure-PHP implementations of...
psr/log                   1.0.0   Common interface for logging libraries
symfony/console           v2.5.12 Symfony Console Component
symfony/finder            v2.5.12 Symfony Finder Component
symfony/polyfill-mbstring v1.2.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/translation       v3.1.2  Symfony Translation Component
```

I'm happy to do more debugging if someone can please suggest how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top and then `$ssh->getLog()` after the error.

Comment: @TobyG did you ever find an answer for this? Same issue here.

Comment: @CodeGodie I didn't.  I've added the 'answer' which was to ignore the warnings, as deployment worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this ticket, I didn't manage to resolve the error messages, but as originally mentioned, the deployment completed fine, so for now I've not done any more investigative work.